# How to add synonyms search in Lucene.net search

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, search, lucene.net

How do I add the filter like synonyms to lucene search. I would like to make lucene search to perform search on synonyms as well. I am using lucene with .net(mvc) platform. I have tried to find the solution for this but did not get the proper way to move ahead.

Any suggestion or help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a TokenFilter and use it with your Analyzer.
in your analyzer add the filter:

```
    public override TokenStream TokenStream(string fieldName, System.IO.TextReader reader)
    {
        TokenStream result = BaseAnalyzer.TokenStream(fieldName, reader);
        result = new SynonymFilter(result, _languages); // injects synonyms.

        return result;
    }
```

Then in the SynonymFilter enter the synonyms in the same position of the original word:

```
    private ITermAttribute _termAtt;
    private ITypeAttribute _typeAtt;
    private IPositionIncrementAttribute _posIncrAtt;
    private Queue<string> _synonymTokenQueue = new Queue<string>();
    private AttributeSource.State _current = null;
```

...

```
     public SynonymFilter(TokenStream input)
        : base(input)
    {
        _termAtt = AddAttribute<ITermAttribute>();
        _typeAtt = AddAttribute<ITypeAttribute>();
        _posIncrAtt = AddAttribute<IPositionIncrementAttribute>();
    }
```

...

```
    public override bool IncrementToken()
    {
        // if our synonymTokens queue contains any tokens, return the next one.
        if (_synonymTokenQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            RestoreState(_current);
            _termAtt.SetTermBuffer(_synonymTokenQueue.Dequeue());
            _typeAtt.Type = "<SYNONYM>";
            _posIncrAtt.PositionIncrement = 0;

            return true;
        }

        try
        {
            if (!input.IncrementToken()) // EOS; iterator exhausted
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_termAtt.Term))
        {

            List<string> synonyms = GetTermSynonyms(_termAtt.Term);

            foreach (string synonym in synonyms)
            {
                _synonymTokenQueue.Enqueue(synonym);
            }
        }

        _current = CaptureState();
        return true;
    }
```

The code examples here are only examples, not a working code(!), i'm sure you can continue from here... :)

Omri

Comment: Working example (but without ITypeAttribute): https://github.com/devhost/Corelicious/blob/master/Corelicious.Lucene/ExpanderFilter.cs